# Can I mix TMC drivers with A4988 on the same RAMPS board?

Tags: stepper-driver, ramps, tmc2130

The closest thing I can find is this [wiki page](https://reprap.org/wiki/A4988_vs_DRV8825_Chinese_Stepper_Driver_Boards#Mixing_A4988_and_DRV8825_stepper_drivers) that state DRV8825 and A4988 can be mixed. However, the TMCs seem different, requiring more connections and offer more features, so I wonder if they can be used on the same RAMPS board with A4988, particularly for X and Y axis.

Comment: If you're going to use modern drivers with SPI or UART connections, you should probably invest in a board that supports them natively (SKR 1.3, 1.4; Fysetc F6, S6; MKS S GEN L) - it's a lot cleaner then compared to monstrous wire harnesses.

To use different drivers - and mix them - just define each driver as the correct type in your configuration.h file:
https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration.h#L687

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can mix different drivers, including the TMC drivers (e.g. using for X and Y only).

How you do that is described in [this instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Upgrading-RAMPS-14-With-TMC2130-Stepper-Drivers/).

---

*Please do note that, from observations, the 8-bit based Arduino boards and shields such as the RAMPS are becoming more or less obsolete; the 32-bit based controller boards are becoming mainstream. Such boards have a lot more potential in execution speed, memory and more available options for peripherals.*